# How to permanently save Picked Time in TimePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, timepicker

I've tried to save picked time permanently by using shared preferences inside future asynchronous with set string and get string inside load_reftime(). Also in Shared Preferences I add selected Time in a set string with .tostring() and I add TimeOfDay.from DateTime(DateTime.parse(prefs.getString(_time))); with DateTime.parse to make sure the picked time is saved and loaded permanently by the time I restart my emulator app.
But the result is the same.

[image: Time set]
[image: The result]

I need advice and a solution to save the selected time to SharedPreferences and change it only when I decide to change Thank you.

[image: 1st code]

[image: 2nd code]

[image: 3rd code]

For the code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BYftWqgBGc7K-ggo1iwrcCwbohAotuS3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please share code where you save after then get time using shared preferences

Comment: The code is in the link picture 1st code, 2nd code and 3rd code. Thank you

Comment: mention , var name to save is selectedTime or selectedClock?

Comment: Both. The link of the code is in my question

Comment: every time  
TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();
 TimeOfDay selectedClock = TimeOfDay.now();
init with TimeOfDay.now , so you will sure to get from shared preferences

Comment: What do you mean? You mean I have to add timeofday.now() in init?

Comment: Second time you get time from shared preferences  , not from existing.

Comment: You mean adding timeofday.now() into void init?

Comment: just give me the code that i have to fix

Comment: Because I'm new in this flutter, can you give me the code you advise? So that I can fix at? Thank you

Comment: how can I share screen? do you have email? let's have some zoom

Comment: I'm waiting for your response

Answer (score 0):

While saving into Sharedpreferences,
save it like this:

```
preferences.setString('time', DateTime(
  DateTime.now().year,
  DateTime.now().month,
  DateTime.now().day,
  endTime!.hour, // TimeOfDay
  endTime!.minute, //TimeOfDay
).toString());
```

And for getting,

```
 time = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(
      DateTime.parse(preferences.getString('time')!));
```

This should fix it!